# What do the terms "white box testing" and "black box testing" mean?

Tags: testing, black-box-testing, white-box-testing

Hi everyone my question is not about programming. Rather it is on software development plans. Can someone explain these 2 to me am getting a bit of confusion:

```
 White box testing
 Blackbox testing
```

Also it would be appreciated if someone gives me some examples about these two. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're being downvoted not only because this question is better to ask at programmers.stackexchange.com, but also because the precise answer to your question is easily accessible by simply googling the heading of your question. Such questions don't belong to StackOverflow or any other site in the StackExchange network.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you googled and still don't understand the difference, you should include in your question what part of the definition you don't understand (e.g. "I read white box testing is this, and black box testing is that, but isn't this actually the same thing?") and phrase the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, as stated in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

- White box testing is the name of the united tests like Junit (Framework). This type of testing check internal structures and workings of your code.
- Blackbox testing is the name that receive functional test like Automated Blackboxing Testing (Framework) ; analyzed the functionality of the code but not its structure.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're wrong that JUnit is used only for white box testing. There is nothing stopping JUnit user from writing black box tests.

Comment: And there is no such thing as "Automated Blackboxing Testing (Framework)"

Comment: For more information about "Automated Testing Framework" you could look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Testing_Framework or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123173/automated-testing-framework for example.

Answer (score 0):

**Black box testing** is the testing process when testers test a software/application manually covering its functionalities and user experience in a naked eye. There is no access of source code to the testers in case of black box testing.
**White box testing** is the process when tester test an application/software including code besides manual testing. Unit test is a part of white box testing. Tester has access on both code and application in case of white box testing.

Answer (score 0):

The black box testers only look at the Application from the outside and check whether all the modules are working fine as expected.

White box testers ensure to take a deep dive into the internal architecture and reusable code  to check whether all the Aplication parts are working fine.